# Ecoinpool setup - error with couchdb

Tags: erlang, couchdb, debian, bitcoin

Im facing an error when test running ecoinpool https://github.com/p2k/ecoinpool .

OS is debian.

```
    root@j064:~/ecoinpool# ./test_launch.sh
==> ecoinpool (compile)
==> ebitcoin (compile)
==> rel (compile)
==> ecoinpool (compile)
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(ecoinpool_test@j064)1> [12:29:23.245][ebitcoin/fatal] config_db - couchbeam:open_or_create_db/3 returned an error:
{ok,"401",
    [{"Server","CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B01)"},
     {"Date","Thu, 30 Aug 2012 12:29:23 GMT"},
     {"Content-Type","application/json"},
     {"Content-Length","67"},
     {"Cache-Control","must-revalidate"}],
    <<"{\"error\":\"unauthorized\",\"reason\":\"Name or password is incorrect.\"}\n">>}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{ebitcoin_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}},[{ecoinpool_test_launch,start,0,[{file,"src/ecoinpool_test_launch.erl"},{line,34}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
root@j064:~/ecoinpool#
```

---

EDIT
This is the error i face now, sadly i can not explain how i came here but the unauthorized error is gone.

```
root@j064:~/ecoinpool# ./test_launch.sh
==> ecoinpool (compile)
==> ebitcoin (compile)
==> rel (compile)
==> ecoinpool (compile)
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(ecoinpool_test@j064)1> {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{ebitcoin_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}},[{ecoinpool_test_launch,start,0,[{file,"src/ecoinpool_test_launch.erl"},{line,34}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
root@j064:~/ecoinpool#
```

Comment: I have posted the new error here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231780/couchdb-init-terminating-in-do-boot-badmatch-error-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Response `401` means that provided BasicAuth user:password pair is invalid.

By default, **ecoinpool** use this configuration for CouchDB access:

```
{db_options, [{basic_auth, {"ecoinpool", "localtest"}}]},
```

You can change this settings in `test_launch.config` file (or other configuration file that you actually use).

Comment: indeed, i did so, otherwise i would not post here.

Comment: {db_options, [{basic_auth, {"username", "password"}}]},
i only changed the username and password, is there anyhting else to change?

Comment: <<"{\"error\":\"unauthorized\",\"reason\":\"Name or password is incorrect.\"}\n">>}  this is i guess the error - so why is it saying the password or username is incorrect?