# Couchdb {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown

Tags: erlang, couchdb

A pool mining software written in Erlang for cryptographic currencies.
https://github.com/p2k/ecoinpool

I currently try to install this software on a debian server but facing the error as described below. Im really new to linux so please excuse if this is a very simple question.

```
root@j064:~/ecoinpool# ./test_launch.sh
==> ecoinpool (compile)
==> ebitcoin (compile)
==> rel (compile)
==> ecoinpool (compile)
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(ecoinpool_test@j064)1> {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{ebitcoin_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}},[{ecoinpool_test_launch,start,0,[{file,"src/ecoinpool_test_launch.erl"},{line,34}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
root@j064:~/ecoinpool#
```

My ecoinconfig looks like this:

```
% This is an example configuration file. Lists are denoted with [...] and tuples
% are denoted with {...}. Together they form a nested structure of names and
% parameters. If you make changes and add or remove options, make sure not to
% have a comma before a closing bracket or curly brace.

[
    % SASL is Erlang's internal error and crash logger; it also logs starting
    % and stopping of certain processes. I set it to "error" here so it won't
    % pollute stdout/stderr.
    {sasl, [
        {errlog_type, error}
    ]},

    % This is ecoinpool's main configuration. The CouchDB connection is
    % configured here.
    {ecoinpool, [
        % The following commented lines are default settings.
        {db_host, "127.0.0.1"},
        % {db_port, 5984},
        % {db_prefix, ""},

        % The next line should be changed, depending on your CouchDB
        % authentication settings:         
        {db_options, [{basic_auth, {"dbuser", "dbpass"}}]},

        % Here you can change ecoinpool's HTTP service port, currently used to
        % serve global RPC functions used by the frontend.
        %{service_port, 8080},

        % The last line in this section contains your blowfish secret key, share
        % this among your servers and don't tell it to anyone else. Minimum key
        % length is 4 bytes, maximum is 56 bytes.
        % If you have pwgen (a password generator), try "pwgen -s 56 1" to get
        % 56 random characters.
        {blowfish_secret, "9Zx95ZQ2P0682MtbSGw8RNLrYhmCBD7jFwzejlv54oLXzB9gGbCfWQUc"}
    ]},

    % This is the ebitcoin configuration. ebitcoin forms a separate application,
    % thus it doesn't share ecoinpool's database settings. If you use the same
    % CouchDB server and authentication, copy it from above.
    {ebitcoin, [
        % You can also disable ebitcoin altogether by uncommenting the following
        % line. Note that you will fall back to the polling system then.
        % {enabled, false},

        {db_host, "127.0.0.1"},
        % {db_port, 5984},
        % {db_prefix, ""},
        {db_options, [{basic_auth, {"dbuser", "dbpass"}}]}
    ]},

    % The third separate application (it also has to be started separately) is
    % the MySQL Replicator. It is used to bridge legacy MySQL worker tables to
    % CouchDB and also stores copies of the shares into a MySQL table.
    {ecoinpool_mysql_replicator, [
        % Again, commented lines are default settings.
        {couchdb_host, "127.0.0.1"},
        %{couchdb_port, 5984},
        %{couchdb_prefix, ""},
        {couchdb_options, [{basic_auth, {"dbuser", "dbpass"}}]},
        %{couchdb_database, "ecoinpool"},

        %{mysql_host, "localhost"},
        %{mysql_port, 3306},
        %{mysql_prefix, ""},
        {mysql_options, [{auth, {"unchanged", "unchanged"}}]},
        %{mysql_database, "ecoinpool"},

        % This is a setting that certainly has to be changed. Configure one or
        % more worker table replicators here (if you have multiple sub-pools).
        % Please only connect one sub-pool to one table or things get jammed up.
        {replicator_configs, [
            % Format: {<ecoinpool sub-pool ID>, <MySQL worker table>, <MySQL sync interval in seconds, 1 or more>}
            {"24aa68ec6c910de0850ed0c575621ec9", "pool_worker", 15}
        ]},

        % Next is your blowfish secret key. Copy it from above.
        {blowfish_secret, "Replace me!"},

        % And the last one, also to be likely changed, is the shares deployer
        % configuration. There are two possible formats here, one with and one
        % without using merged mining. The config ID is used as basename for
        % saving the deployment state file and for the "source" column.
        {share_deployer_configs, [
            % Non-MM Format: {<config ID string>, <pool name>, <MySQL shares table>, <MySQL write interval in seconds, 0 allowed>}
            {"ltc_test_shares", "ltc-test", "shares", 60},
            % MM Format: {<config ID string>, <main pool name>, <aux pool name>, <MySQL shares table>, <MySQL write interval in seconds, 0 allowed>}
            {"btc_nmc_test_shares", "btc-test", "nmc-test", "shares", 60}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

Comment: Do you have couchdb and mysql running? Also it seems like you need to change user credentials in your config file.

Comment: % The third separate application (it also has to be started separately) is
    % the MySQL Replicator. It is used to bridge legacy MySQL worker tables to
    % CouchDB and also stores copies of the shares into a MySQL table.

I did not entered mysql data because of this comment.
Fields with dbuser/dbpass have my dbuser and pass in it. Unchanged means i did not changed anything.

Couchdb is running and working.

Answer (score 1):

A solution has been posted here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=56068.msg1200054#msg1200054:

> In case anyone else encounters this same problem, it appears to be a case of source code atrophy. The most recent builds of ecoinpool's dependencies no longer work together as expected. Pegging the dependencies to versions around the same time as p2k's last commit solved it for me:
>
> Code: (rebar.config)
>
> ```
> {sub_dirs, ["apps/ecoinpool", "apps/ebitcoin", "rel"]}.
>
> {deps, [
>     {protobuffs, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs.git", "e0f5f6ea4c3dcb4e7b824496d2b48333fbd5a8c8"}},
>     {ejson, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/benoitc/ejson.git", "820ff1725008e664293b88e13c16193857afc072"}},
>     {oauth, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/refuge/erlang-oauth.git", "f332b77371d334d0faa13e106d0c36f948b325b6"}},
>     {ibrowse, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse.git", "eb8b62cf84ccae141700c8fd251277df8be27f28"}},
>     {mochiweb, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/mochi/mochiweb.git", "b7f3693a9008de6d31a67174f7184fe24093a1b4"}},
>     {couchbeam, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam.git", "7148bbdb19aca91b7b74e5392a23c94d33ca4e27"}},
>     {log4erl, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/SemanticSugar/log4erl.git", "ec580f75ef9e28dfcfac92dc0d42c435520bd3d7"}},
>     {mysql, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/elbrujohalcon/erlang-mysql-driver.git", "1dd4e22a80546fa1bda81607d6397a549fd791ae"}},
>     {epgsql, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/wg/epgsql.git", "fc434772276475ac4e5b0bed6b18ed4732502156"}}
> ]}.
> ```